# Dynamically generating arguments Clap

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, clap

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically generating arguments from input arguments with Clap.

What I'm trying to emulate with Clap is the following python code:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", type=str, nargs="*")
(input_args, additional_args) = parser.parse_known_args()
for arg in input_args:
  parser.add_argument(f'--{arg}-bar', required=true, type=str)

additional_config = parser.parse_args(additional_args)
```

So that you can do the following in your command:

```sh
./foo.py -i foo bar baz --foo-bar foo --bar-bar bar --baz-bar bar
```

and have the additional arguments be dynamically generated from the first arguments. Not sure if it's possible to do in Clap but I assumed it was maybe possible due to the *Readme* stating you could use the builder pattern to dynamically generate arguments[1].

So here is my naive attempt of trying to do this.

```rust
use clap::{Arg, App};

fn main() {
  let mut app = App::new("foo")
               .arg(Arg::new("input")
               .short('i')
               .value_name("INPUT")
               .multiple(true)
               .required(true));
  let matches = app.get_matches_mut();
  let input: Vec<_> = matches.values_of("input").unwrap().collect()
  for i in input {
    app.arg(Arg::new(&*format!("{}-bar", i)).required(true))
  }
}
```

Which does not obviously having the compiler scream at you for both `!format` lifetime and `app.arg` I'm mostly interesting in solving how I could generate new arguments to the `app` which then could be matched against again. I'm quite new to rust so it's quite possible this is not possible with Clap.

[1] https://github.com/clap-rs/clap

Comment: Unfortunately according to this open issue this is not currently supported in Clap: https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/1880

Answer (score 1):

> I assumed it was maybe possible due to the Readme stating you could use the builder pattern to dynamically generate arguments[1].

Dynamically generating argument means that, you can `.arg` with runtime values and it'll work fine (aka the entire CLI doesn't need to be fully defined at compile-time, this distinction doesn't exist in Python as everything is done at runtime).

What you're doing here is significantly more complicated (and specialised, and odd) as you're *passing through* unknown parameters then re-parsing them.

Now first of all, you literally can't reuse `App` in clap: most of its methods (very much including `get_matches`) take `self` and therefore "consume" the App and return something else, either the original App or a result. Although you can `clone` the original App before you `get_matches` it I guess.

But I don't think that's useful here: though I have not tried it should be possible do do what you want using [`TrailingVarArg`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/enum.AppSettings.html#variant.TrailingVarArg): this would collect all trailing arguments into a single positional arg slice ([you will probably need `AllowLeadingHyphen` as well](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/558#issuecomment-230009628)), then you can create a *second* `App` with dynamically generated parameters in order to parse that sub-set of arguments ([`get_matches_from` will parse from an iterator rather than the env args](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/struct.App.html#method.get_matches_from), this is useful for testing... or for this exact sort of situations).